Creating hard links from and to the same network volume
I am trying to populate a folder with a "copy" of files from a fairly complicated and deep folder structure. So I do not duplicate the files I want to use hardlinks to the original files.
This is the command I am trying:
find /Volumes/Multimedia/Photos -name "*.HEIC" | xargs -I {} ln {} /Volumes/Multimedia/List

But I get the following error:
ln: /Volumes/Multimedia/List/Photo1.HEIC: Operation not supported

The Photos and List folders are in the same AFP network volume (also tried on an SMB volume with the same error). Any ideas of what can be wrong? or any other command to achieve the intended result?
